# Elementary proof: $C^\infty$ dense in Riemann Integrable functions space

Tags: integration, derivatives, riemann-integration, smooth-functions

How can we prove in an elementary fashion that any Riemann integrable function can be approximated by a sequence of $C^{\infty}$ functions? More precisely, for $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ how can we find $f_n\in C^{\infty}([a,b])$ such that:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{a}^b |f_n(x)-f(x)|=0$$?

Comment: A uniform limit of continuous functions must be continuous. But not all Riemann integrable functions are continuous.

Comment: I have edited my post. You are right!

Comment: You want to omit the "approximated uniformly" part, and say something like "is an $L^1$-limit of $C^{\infty}$ functions". And probably don't use the notation $C^{\infty}([a,b]),$ as this notation typically means the sup metric is being used, and for what you're asking we're only interested in the fact that the functions are $C^{\infty}.$

Comment: Yes, but in an elementary way. I know that $C^\infty$ is dense in $L^p$.

Comment: First approximate $f$ in $L^1$ norm with step functions, approximate each indicator function (on intervals) with continuous function and pick some polynomials by Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This is tedious but elementary:

If $f$ is Riemann integrable there is a sequence of partitions $P_n$ such that
$L(f,P_n) \to \int f$. Without loss of generality, we can assume the partitions are nested.
We can also assume that the number of points in $P_n$ satisfies $|P_n| \ge n$.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable it is bounded and we can assume $|f| \le B$.

Each partition defines a step function $s_n$ that is constant in the subintervals of
the partition. We have $\int s_n = L(f,P_n)$.  Now modify the step function $s_n$ so that it is continuous in the following way:

Suppose the partition is $x_0=a,x_1,...,x_m=b$ and let $\alpha_k = \sup_{t \in [x_k,x_{k+1}]} f(t)$. Pick a $\delta>0$ so that the points
$x_0, x_1-\delta, x_1+\delta, x_2-\delta, x_2+ \delta,...,x_{m-1}-\delta, x_{m-1}+\delta, x_m$ still form a partition with the obvious ordering **and** $\delta < {1 \over m^2}$.
Define $f_n$ by linearly interpolating  $s_n$ through the points
$(x_0,\alpha_0)$, $(x_1-\delta, \alpha_0)$, $(x_1+\delta, \alpha_1)$, $...$, $(x_{m-1}+\delta, \alpha_{m-1})$, $(x_m,\alpha_{m-1})$. $f_n$ is clearly continuous and bounded by $B$.
By construction we have $\int |s_n-f_n| \le (m-1)B \delta \le {1 \over n} B$.

Then $\int |f_n-f| \le \int |f_n-s_n| + \int |s_n -f| \le \int f - L(f,P_n) + {1 \over n} B$.

As @lzralbu noted in the comments below, the $f_n$ are just continuous. not smooth,
so this is not as elementary as I intended.

One could follow @lzralbu's suggestion or rely on the fact that the polynomials are dense in the continuous functions.

Comment: But the $f_n$ aren't smooth. Instead of linear interpolation, I think you could use bump functions to achieve smoothness directly.

Comment: @lzralbu: Ah yes, I forgot to finish. The polynomials are dense in the continuous functions.